# Seeking Mobile App to insert customized roads for navigation?

Tags: software-recommendations, route, mobile, offline, navigation

I want to know if there is a mobile app (for cellphone) where I can insert my line features (roads) and polygons features (fields), all in vector form (.shp) and somehow navigate with that information.
Instead of using downloaded OpenStreetMap maps I want to download my own shapes.

The purpose of that is inserting private roads and to navigate from Point A to point B just as a regular Navigator would do.
The idea is knowing what the fastest route is, the shortest route, the better for trucks, cars, bikes, walking....

The current option is using Navigator from ESRI, but every license is really expensive, and I am looking for a free App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SWMAPS for Android it's great and free and reads and writes shapefiles it also accepts raster tiles mbtiles for offline Base maps/imagery